# change routes in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, custom-routes

Im working with ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.3, devise 1.5.3, **I need to change the devise routes**, I already **changed the default routes**, like login and logout, but I need to change the others routes, for example:

`http://localhost:3000/password/new`

I need that, when the user click the link did you forget your password? go to:

`http://localhost:3000/recovery_password`

in my routes I tried:

```
get "recovery_password", :to => "devise/passwords#new"                                    
get 'recovery_password' => 'devise_passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
```

but don't works, please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this. It should works. ;)

```rb
# change :devise_model to :users, or :admins or any name of your devise model 
devise_for :devise_model do
    get 'recovery_password' => "devise/passwords#new"
end
```

and you can use this in view like this.

```
link_to 'Forgot you password?', recovery_password_url
```

**PS. if you have customize devise controller. You should tell the router first, and change devise controller to your customize controller name.**

Comment: Now devise is update to version 2.0.0 look at github page by click [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)